# Firebase queryOrderedByChild doesn't work with FIRDataEventType.Value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to have my elements sorted by the server but my code doesn't seem to be working. Suppose I have this code

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("children")
let sortedRef = ref.queryOrderedByChild("height")
ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {snapshot in
    print(snapshot.value!)
})
```

The code returns

```
{
    adam = { height = 120; };
    bart = { height = 100; };
}
```

Which is how the data is displayed in the Firebase console as is (e.g., sorted by key name).

If I use .ChildAdded instead, it will return the items in the correct order. However the handler will be called for each items one by one which is not what I want.

Of course you can argue that since I'm getting all the elements with .Value, I can just then sort it on the client side. But is there anyway that I can use .Value and have the elements sorted by the sever?

Thanks

Comment: I think the issue is how the query is formed vs. how your firebase structure is. I don't think you are going to be able to do it that way - you'll need a deep query on /children/height because height is not a direct child of of the children/child name node. Not sure though. Can you post a snippet of your Firebase structure? As text please, no images (Firebase Dashboard->Three Dots (?) on right->Export. Then copy/paste.